# Kendo UI Gantt Chart refreshing datasource

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, kendo-ui, kendo-gantt

I have a Kendo UI Gantt Chart which uses a JSON as datasource. After modifying the datasource, if I delete the chart and reload it again, the datasource will refresh but the draggable property won't work anymore. And if I refresh it like this

```
var gantt = $("#gantt").data("kendoGantt");
              gantt.dataSource.data = tasksDataSource;
              gantt.refresh();
```

it won't load the new values.
How can I refresh the gantt chart without losing any of the properties?

Answer (score 2):

```
 var dataSource = new kendo.data.GanttDataSource({
            data: tasksDataSource
        });
        gantt.setDataSource(dataSource);
        gantt.dataSource.read();
```

Comment: please put some details... what to do with this piece of code.

Comment: This works just fine, if setting to a new datasource then it must be a 'kendo.data.GanttDataSource' object. For me .read() was not necessary

Answer (score 1):

Assigning to `dataSource` field of the Kendo UI Gantt will have not effect on the widget. Use the `setDataSource` method instead.

```
var gantt = $("#gantt").data("kendoGantt");
gantt.setDataSource(tasksDataSource);
```

The `refresh()` function will only re-render the Gantt using currently loaded data items. To force the Gantt chart to reload its data from it datasources use the `read` function on the `dataSource` and `dependencies` datasource like this.

```
var gantt = $("#gantt").data("kendoGantt");
gantt.dataSource.read();
gantt.dependencies.read();
```

There is a warning about this in the GanttDataSource api [here.](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/gantt#fields-dataSource)
The documentation of the setDataSource method is [here.](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/gantt#methods-setDataSource)

Comment: After doing this, sorting of the fields are not working.